# Junit 5 Test Suites

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to migrate a Project from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5.8.2 with junit-platform-suite-api 1.8.2. We used to organize our test classes in test suites. But if I use the @Suite annotation with @SelectClasses the test runner finds no test methods at all. When running a specific test class directly everything is fine. This happens in eclipse and gradle builds.

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectClasses({
    TestA.class
})
public class ImportantTestSuite {
}
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

public class TestA {

    @Test
    public void reallyImportantTest() {
        assertEquals(2, 1 + 1)
    }

}
```

build.gradle looks like this

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
  testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.8.2'
  testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    minHeapSize = '1024m'
    maxHeapSize = '1024m'
    include '**/*ImportantTestSuite*'
    ignoreFailures = true
    testLogging {
      exceptionFormat 'full'
      events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
    }
  }
```

Any idea how to organize the suites on class basis?

Edit:

[Are test suites considered deprecated in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565724/are-test-suites-considered-deprecated-in-junit5)

I already read this answers. As far as I see I'm using that apporach with @Suite and @SelectClasses and not the runner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are test suites considered deprecated in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565724/are-test-suites-considered-deprecated-in-junit5)

Comment: Do you have something like this in your `build.gradle`: `tasks.named('test') {
 useJUnitPlatform()
}` AFAIK, this is necessary with JUnit 5. :)

Comment: @cyberbrain Nope

Comment: @ahuemmer  yep --> test { useJUnitPlatform()....}
Running single test methods is working

Comment: cannot reproduce any issue. add your imports, gradle config etc that is neccessary context for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The junit-platform-suite-engine was missing...

See: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#junit-platform-suite-engine

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
  testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
  testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.8.2'
  **testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-engine:1.8.2'**
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.25 (part of the Eclipse 2022-09 simultaneous release) should improve the support for JUnit 5:

> ### test suite wizard JUnit 5 support
>
> The **New JUnit Test Suite Wizard** has been enhanced to now allow the creation of a JUnit 5 test suite using the `@Suite` annotation.
>
> To open the **New JUnit Test Suite Wizard** for the current package, go to `New > Other > Java > JUnit > JUnit Test Suite`.
>
> [image: Test Suite Wizard -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.25/images/test-suite-wizard-junit5.png]
>
> The result of this is:
>
> [image: JUnit 5 Test Suite]